# Can not copy (much) between instances in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste

I have a user who is not able to copy much data from one instance of Excel to another. Copying and pasting within an instance works fine, but if I open up two instances I quickly get the error:

```
Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data.
```

What is really weird is the circumstances under which the error appears.
Ways to produce this error:

- Copy one cell back and forth a few times, tends to fail on the third time.
- Copy one cell into a document with lots of other stuff, works about 10 times.
- Copy one cell from a document with lots of other stuff, into a blank document, works about 3 times.
- Open a third instance and copy a cell back and forth, it will work one or two times and then produce the error.
- Open a fourth instance, it will work with any sheet, until you get the error, then it will work with none of them.

What does not affect if the error appears:

- If the workbook is marco-enabled
- If Excel is in Safe mode

Closing a sheet (but not the instance) and then opening a new sheet allows more copying and pasting... for a little while.

I have a ton of RAM available and Excel isn't eating up memory. 
I have no idea what the cause of this could be, and it's driving me nuts. Please help.

**Update:** Copying and pasting with `Paste Special/XML Spreadsheet` works even after regular Copy/Paste has failed. This does not help in my case, because the spreadsheet I am trying to copy has pivot Tables.

**Update2:** Copying and then pasting with `Paste Special/Microsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object` and then double clicking on the result allows me move the data between instances, but this is a ridiculously over convoluted process and I would still like to know what happening so that I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: Are you coping links or functions with code behind?

Comment: @PortlandRunner It happens even if I copy just a single plain-text cell that I just typed out. Letters or numbers, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just as a test, try copying to notepad, clear your windows clipboard and then copy to the other excel sheet a few times and see if it crashes.

Comment: @PortlandRunner It does not crash.

Comment: @PortlandRunner As I said above, running in safe mode does not help.

Comment: I've seen this problem before. Unfortunately, the machine was formatted and reinstalled due to time constraints, so I never got a chance to figure it out. My advice would be to keep one instance of Excel running at any given time.

Comment: This occurs on my system if MouseWithoutBorders is set to share the clipboard, as it is attempting to copy the data from excel over the network to another computer. The same behavior may occur if an RDP or VNC client is open or connected.

Comment: @RichieFrame That's handy to know, but none of those things are happening on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the Spreadsheet contains corrupted (or too much) cell style data. The number of cell styles seems to build up over time until something gives.

To clean your spreadsheet, run it through [XLStyesTool](http://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/net4-0-version-of-the-xlstylestool-is-now-available/) and then try copying and pasting again.

[image]